# Selenium Chromedriver: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 98, so returning the closest version found: a no-op implementation

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
Mar 08, 2022 9:03:17 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 98, so returning the closest version found: a no-op implementation
Mar 08, 2022 9:03:17 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
INFO: Unable to find CDP implementation matching 98.
Mar 08, 2022 9:03:17 PM org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver lambda$new$3
WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for . You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.1.2` where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.
```

Comment: Kindly assist anyone as i get this error when running my test on intellij